# Regex remove all alphabic and punctuation execpt "."(dot) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to relpace all non digit char expect ".". dot should be allowed only once. That's mean

```
4.2 ->ok
a4.21 ->not ok
14.22 ->ok
2.-4 ->not ok
21..43 ->not ok
```

How can I write regex for this?

I tried /[^0-9.]/g. But multiple dots accept here.

Comment: Seems like `\b\d+\.\d+\b` should be enough, https://regex101.com/r/lnLljm/1, at least based on the data you provided

Comment: Try `/(?<=\..*)\.|[^0-9.]/g`. If there is a problem with the lookbehind, try `replace(/(\..*)\.|[^0-9.]/g, '$1')`. Please let know if either helped.

Comment: Does the OP want to remove any character which is neither a digit nor a dot as stated with the OP's question or does the OP want to test the validity of a possible number candidate as one could guess from the OP's pseudo code which states `ok` / `not ok`?

Comment: @noob_developer I added an answer, I hope it will work as per your requirement/expectation.

Answer (score 0):

from what you are writing it appears that you want to validate a (potentially decimal) number from some kind of user input.

I would suggest to do it in two steps

1. trim the input
2. validate the number

you can trim the input with the regex you mentioned, or with simple mystring.trim() if whitespaces is what you care about.
Then you can use `!mystring.isNaN()` to validate the correctness of the number (or `mystring.parseFloat()` if output should be always decimal].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `regex` to validate the decimal point numbers.

```
/^\d*.?\d+$/
```

Explanation **:**

`^\d*` - Matches zero or number of digits.
`.?\d+` - Matches an optional decimal point`(.)` followed by at least one digit.

Live Demo **:**

```js
function checkValue() {
  const inputVal = document.getElementById('numberfield').value;
  var regex = /^\d*.?\d+$/
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = inputVal.match(regex) ? 'Valid' : 'Not valid'
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id="numberfield" onblur="checkValue()"/>
<span id="result"></span>
```